# `pip install .` throws `[Errno 28] No space left on device`

Tags: python, pip, package, setup.py

I am trying to install a package I developed locally. The structure of the directories is this:

```
├── mycode
│   └── __init__.py
|   └── somefuncs.py
├── Data
│   └── ...
└── Notebooks
    └── ...
```

For convenience I save some jupyter notebooks and analysis data on `Notebooks` and `Data`. In the `MANIFEST.in` I have included the lines

```
exclude Notebooks/*.*
exclude Data/*.*
```

And in the setup.py I have included the line `packages=setuptools.find_packages(exclude=['Data', 'Notebooks'])` as well.

However, when I run `pip install .` I get a large message with the structure
`'/tmp/pip-req-build-ymqucesw/X', '[Errno 28] No space left on device'`, where `X` are all of the files in `Notebooks`, `Data`, and `mycode`.

It looks like `pip` is ignoring `MANIFEST.in` and `setup.py` configuration. Is there any option to effectively ignore those files while keeping them at the same location as they currently are?

Comment: Based on the error message, why do you think `pip` is ignoring `MANIFEST.ini` and `setup.py` configuration? Why do you think it is not the case that, as the error message says, there is simply not enough space left in the device?

Comment: What I intend to do is to avoid `pip` reading the rest of the files using `MANIFEST` and `setup`. The rest of the files that have to be integrated, which are mere scripts, don't occupy more than 50 kb, and I have that space in the disk.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the question using the command `python setup.py sdist` instead of `pip install .`. `MENIFEST.in` file must contain

```
prune Notebooks
prune Data
```

and `setup.py` file must have the attributes `packages=setuptools.find_packages(exclude=['Data', 'Notebooks'])` and `include_package_data=True`.